# What does mean some eigenvalues of the Hessian are positive? How to fix it?

Tags: r, discrete-data, multinomial-logit, hessian

I prepared a research design with the discrete choice method. I have 2 labeled alternatives, 5 attributes for an alternative, and 6 attributes for an alternative. I want to analyze my data with multinomial logit in the R apollo package R. However, I have an error. But I don't know what this error means and how I should go about to fix it. I would be very happy if you could give your opinion on this.

This is the error:

```
 "Calculating log-likelihood at equal shares (LL(0)) for applicable models...
Calculating log-likelihood at observed shares from estimation data (LL(c)) for applicable models...
Calculating LL of each model component...
Calculating other model fit measures
Computing covariance matrix using analytical gradient.
 0%....25%....50%....75%...100%
WARNING: Some eigenvalues of the Hessian are positive, indicating convergence to a saddle point!
Computing score matrix...
Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(diag(varcov)) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(diag(robvarcov)) : NaNs produced
```

This is the R script:

```
install.packages("apollo")
### Clear memory
rm(list = ls())


### Load Apollo library
library(apollo)
library(tidyverse)

### Initialise code
apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control = list(
  modelName       = "MNL_Deneme",
  modelDescr      = "Simple MNL model on mode choice SP data",
  indivID         = "id"
)
library(readxl)
database <- read_excel("ayakkabi.xlsx")
View(database)
attach(database)
apollo_beta=c (asc_ev = 0,
               asc_nokta= 0,
               b_ucret_ev= 0,
               b_m1ev= 0,
               b_m2ev= 0,
               b_m3ev= 0,
               b_h1ev= 0,
               b_h2ev= 0,
               b_h3ev= 0,
               b_h4ev= 0,
               b_s1ev= 0,
               b_s2ev= 0,
               b_s3ev= 0,
               b_s4ev= 0,
               b_b1ev= 0,
               b_b2ev= 0,
               b_ucret_n= 0,
               b_m1n= 0,
               b_m2n= 0,
               b_h1n= 0,
               b_h2n= 0,
               b_h3n= 0,
               b_h4n= 0,
               b_a1n= 0,
               b_a2n= 0,
               b_a3n= 0,
               b_a4n= 0,
               b_b1n= 0,
               b_b2n= 0,
               b_u1n= 0,
               b_u2n= 0,
               b_u3n= 0,
               b_u4n= 0
)
apollo_fixed = c("asc_ev","b_m1ev","b_h1ev", "b_s1ev","b_b1ev","b_m1n", "b_h1n","b_a1n","b_b1n","b_u1n")

apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()

apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
  ### Attach inputs and detach after function exit
  apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
  on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))
  ### Create list of probabilities P
  P = list()
  ### List of utilities: these must use the same names as in mnl_settings, order is irrelevant
  V = list()
  V[['ev']] = asc_ev + b_ucret_ev*ucret_ev + b_m1ev*(metot_ev==0) + b_m2ev*(metot_ev==1) +b_m3ev*(metot_ev==2) +
    b_h1ev*(hiz_ev==0) + b_h2ev*(hiz_ev==1) + b_h3ev*(hiz_ev==2) + b_h4ev*(hiz_ev==3) +
    b_s1ev*(saat_ev==0) + b_s2ev*(saat_ev==1) + b_s3ev*(saat_ev==2) + b_s4ev*(saat_ev==3) +
    b_b1ev*(bilgi_ev==0) + b_b2ev*(bilgi_ev==1)
  
  V[['nokta']] = asc_nokta + b_ucret_n*(ucret_nokta) + b_m1n*(metot_nokta==0) + b_m2n*(metot_nokta==1) +
    b_h1n*(hiz_nokta==0) + b_h2n*(hiz_nokta==1) + b_h3n*(hiz_nokta==2) + b_h4n*(hiz_nokta==3) +
    b_a1n*(acik_nokta==0) + b_a2n*(acik_nokta==1) + b_a3n*(acik_nokta==2) + b_a4n*(acik_nokta==3) +
    b_b1n*(bilgi_nokta==0) +b_b2n*(bilgi_nokta==1) +
    b_u1n*(uzaklik_nokta==0) + b_u2n*(uzaklik_nokta==1) + b_u3n*(uzaklik_nokta==2) + b_u4n*(uzaklik_nokta==3)
  ### Define settings for MNL model component
  mnl_settings = list(
    alternatives = c(ev=1, nokta=2),
    avail = 1,
    choiceVar = secim,
    V = V)
  ### Compute probabilities using MNL model
  P[["model"]] = apollo_mnl(mnl_settings, functionality)
  
  ### Take product across observation for same individual
  P = apollo_panelProd(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  
  ### Prepare and return outputs of function
  P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  return(P)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
# ################################################################# #

model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL OUTPUTS                                               ####
# ################################################################# #
apollo_modelOutput(model,modelOutput_settings=list(printPVal=TRUE))
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO SCREEN)                               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_modelOutput(model)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #
#---- FORMATTED OUTPUT (TO FILE, using model name)               ----
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- #

apollo_saveOutput(model)
```

Comment: Please format the scripts properly.

Comment: The error message is clear: "indicating convergence to a saddle point!"  The algorithm has not succeeded.  You need to find ways to steer it towards the global optimum or at least a local minimum.  If this function allows you to specify starting values, then your task is to find a reasonable set of such values and provide them as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In the applications I have experience with, this has to do with multicollinearity and normalization. If, for example, your model has consumers selecting products offered by different companies and includes an intercept for each company and you do not hold one fixed at zero, then I believe you'd encounter this problem. Also, if your model includes a product characteristic that is perfectly correlated with the company (i.e., only one company offers a product with that characteristic), I believe you would also encounter the problem them. In each of these cases, one variable is a linear combination of others in the model. In the former case, the indicator for company 1 is one less the sum of the indicator for the remaining companies. In the latter case, the indicator for the product characteristic is equal to the indicator for the company that offers the product. I think that's what could be causing the convergence to a saddle point.